# Absolute value in Linear programming problem

Tags: linear-programming

I have this problem, where I have to reformulate it as a linear programming problem.

Minimize   $ 2x_1 +3 \vert {x_2-10}\vert $

subject to $\vert {x_1+2}\vert + \vert {x_2}\vert ≤5  $

The subject is new to me. Can anyone help?

Comment: $t\geq |x|$ is equivalent to $t\geq x$ and $t\geq -x$.

Comment: Don´t forget to mark answers as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, the constraint $\vert {x_1+2}\vert + \vert {x_2}\vert ≤5$ corresponds to:
$$\pm(x_1+2)\pm x_2 \le 5 \iff 
\begin{cases}\ \ \ \ \ x_1+2+x_2\le 5\\
-(x_1+2)+x_2\le 5\\
\ \ \ \ \ x_1+2-x_2\le 5\\
-(x_1+2)-x_2\le 5\\
\end{cases}$$
The feasible region is:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Since $x_2<10$, then the original problem can be reformulated as:
$$\text{Minimize} \ \ 2x_1+3(10-x_2) \ \ \text{subject to:}\\
 \begin{cases}x_1+x_2\le 3\\
x_1-x_2\ge -7\\
x_1-x_2\le 3\\
x_1+x_2\ge -7\\
\end{cases}$$
The answer is: $f(-2,5)=11$. To be verified: [Original](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize%202x_1%20%2B3%7Cx_2-10%7C%20subject%20to%20%7Cx_1%2B2%7C%20%2B%20%7Cx_2%7C%20%E2%89%A45) and [Reformulated](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize%202x_1%2B3(10-x_2)%20subject%20to%20x_1%2Bx_2%3C%3D3,%20x_1-x_2%3E%3D-7,%20x_1-x_2%3C%3D3,%20x_1%2Bx_2%3E%3D-7).